# Iterate through an array of objects and calculate one single property value

Tags: javascript

So let's say we do have this array:

```js
const db = [
{name: 'Coffe', price: '10'},
{name: 'Stackoverflow Stickers', price: '7.5'},
{name: 'Nike Air Force', price: '100'},
// more objects in similar format (long list)
]
```

So what I want to do is iterate through array and calculate all prices of each object value, in this case price.

What I tried, but somehow it doesn't work works:

```js
let total = 0;
data.map((d) => (d.total += total))
setTotal(totalValues)
```

Comment: `.map()` is the wrong tool for this but other than that, there is an average of one error per line in the code. I suggest writing a simple loop first and [ensure it works properly](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.reduce` function:

```js
const total = db.reduce(
  (total, curr) => total + parseFloat(curr.price),
  0
);
setTotal(total);
```

Read more: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can use array reduce for this

don't forget to parseFloat your string in db data

```js
const db = [
{name: 'Coffe', price: '10'},
{name: 'Stackoverflow Stickers', price: '7.5'},
{name: 'Nike Air Force', price: '100'},
]

let total = db.reduce((previous, current) => (previous + parseFloat(current.price)), 0)
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below changes to fix the issue. Inside map function instead of `(d) => (d.total += total)` use `(d) => (total+= Number(d.price))`.

```js
const data = [
{name: 'Coffe', price: '10'},
{name: 'Stackoverflow Stickers', price: '7.5'},
{name: 'Nike Air Force', price: '100'},
// more objects in similar format (long list)
]

let total = 0;
data.map((d) => (total+= Number(d.price)))
console.log(total)
```

**Note:** Instead of using `map` , use `forEach` or a normal loop for these kind of operations. Like this:

```
data.forEach((d) => (total+= Number(d.price)))
```

Comment: Please do not use `.map()` for simple array iteration. Use `.forEach()` or a normal loop to do that.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ for suggesting the better way. I used ```map``` previously just for providing a solution similar to the already used approach . I've updated my answer now :)